# Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web: Creating Service Reference to WCF Data Service 5.0.0.0 Causes Custom Tool Error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wcf-data-services-client

At least in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web, when creating a Service Reference to a WCF Data Services 5.0.0.0 service with truly RESTful URL (routed properly without the .svc URI or file):

1. You need to add /$metadata to the service URL to get the metadata
2. There is an error after downloading/creating the .edmx and .datasvcmap that "Cannot find custom tool 'DataServicesCoreClientGenerator' on this system."
3. When trying to delete the incomplete Service Reference, an error occurs: "The .svcmap file cannot be found. It may have been moved or deleted. To generate a new .svcmap file, delete the service reference and add it again.". First, I DID just try to delete it, and B, it looks like there is a .datasvcmap file there, not a .svcmap.

Am I missing some tool, or a link to the datasvcutil.exe in VS 2012 Express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved issues two and three by installing [WCF Data Services 5.3.0 RTM Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35840).

Hope this helps.